# Django primarykey serializer "This field may not be null" while allow_null=True

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I've been struggling with this problem.

I am not sure what I'm missing.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions..!!

**models.py**:

```
co_manager = models.ManyToManyField(BookRunner, blank=True, null=True, related_name="deal_co_manager")
```

**views.py**:

```
 class DealAdminViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      queryset = Deal.objects.all()
      serializer_class = CreateDealSerializer

      def create(self, request, format=None):
          data = ...all things data here.
          serializer = CreateDealSerializer(data=deal)
          print serializer
          co_manager_array = []
          if serializer.is_valid():
              serializer.save()
              return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
          else:
              return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializer.py**:

```
class CreateDealSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    co_manager = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, many=True, queryset=BookRunner.objects.all(), required=False)
```

Comment: PrimaryKeyRelatedField relates to primary key, it cannot be null, try DataSerializer or CharField

Comment: Primary Key should never be a `null`.

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield - it says here it can be...

Comment: You should post the full error stacktrace

Comment: I decided to just get rid of the serializer and added the add() function in the view after the serializer returned the object that was created. This was the only way I could make it work...

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest editing your views, more like this,

```
class DealAdminViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Deal.objects.all()
  serializer_class = CreateDealSerializer

  def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
      if serializer.is_valid():
          serializer.save()
          return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
      return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Without showing your models, the help anyone could offer is pretty much limited. Please let me know, if anything comes up.

Also, your serializers,

```
class CreateDealSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    co_manager = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, many=True, queryset=BookRunner.objects.all())
```

The error is triggering because, in your models the field `co_manager` is not defined as `null=True`. If you want to save the above field as `null`, then change in your models.py,

```
co_manager = models.ForeignKey(Target_table_name, null=True, blank=True)
```

The error won't be raised, when null value is stored.

Comment: I have null as true as well.

Comment: could add your models??

Comment: You could do this with a model serializer, without giving much thoughts into it..

Comment: do you have blank=True in your model fields?? if not serializer won't accept null values... may be that could be the problem..

Answer (score 4):

Just send an empty list if serializer is set with 
many = True, 
allow_null=True

from serliazer:

```
many_field = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=qs, read_only=False, many=True, allow_null=True)

class Meta:
    model = ModelName
    fields = (
        'many_field ',
         ...)
    extra_kwargs = {
        'many_field': {'required': False},
    }
```

and in the requests data:

```
 data = {'NOT_many_field': None,
 'many_field': []}
```